# animate the appearance of table view cells

Tags: animation, tableview, cell

I have a table view with many headers. The cells of every header are hidden. These cells will appear when the user presses the header.
Suppose I have header 3 under header 2 under header 1. when I press on header 1 the cells of that header must appear, and header 2 and 3 must be pushed down and not covered by the cells of 1. I succeeded in pushing the 2 headers, but with no animation. What I want is to animate the appearance of the cells when a section is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
```